# Css input shape

Tags: css, input, shapes

I wrote this css to make a form have the little openid logo on the left but I would like the form to retain its default look rather than get that right angley look.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.openid-input {
  background: url("http://id.gesellix.de/logo/openid_small_logo_white.gif") no-repeat scroll left center transparent;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-left: 18px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" tabindex="100" class="openid-input">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: need more detail, what *right angley look*

Comment: I think we need to see the code for the form, too - it's very hard to visualize a completely unknown form.

Comment: There is nothing in your CSS that would change the look of the input besides the size and background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default input styling gets overridden as soon as you change the background property.  You must set CSS styling to mimic the default styling, but this can only be accomplished with CSS3.  The following styles match closely on my system:

```
border:1px #e4e4e4 solid;
box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px #000000;
```

I've [created an example here (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/dYb8G/).

You can get pretty close to the default styling without CSS3 with just:

```
border:1px #cccccc solid;
border-top:2px #666666 solid;
```